# Getting current location in Android Studio app

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am developing my first Android app which should get the **latitude** and **longitude** of an android device and send it via a web service to a template document.

I followed the guide of getting the location from http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html.

This is the code from my .java class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GetLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    EditText textLat;
    EditText textLong;
    EditText lat;
    EditText lon;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_location);

        textLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        textLong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    private boolean isGPSEnabled() {
        LocationManager cm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return cm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            lon.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.getGpsLocation){
            if(!isGPSEnabled()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage("Please activate your GPS Location!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();
            } else {
                textLat.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
                textLong.setText(String.valueOf(lon));
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I don't get any errors but when I am tapping the button which should get the coordinates, **I get 'null' text in both views**.

I also have included permissions for internet, access fine and coarse location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doesn't look like you actually ever connected to the `mGoogleApiClient` by calling `mGoogleApiClient.connect` in onStart as stated in the docs. I'm assuming you never actually get a callback to `onConnected` so you have no data set. You can easily test that if you put a log in `onConnected`

Answer (score 2):

[I have written detailed tutorial covering this topic here on demonuts.com.You can find more description here and also you can download whole demo source code for better understanding.](http://demonuts.com/2016/12/30/android-get-current-locationlatitude-laongitude-of-android-device/)

First of all, put this in gradle file

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

then implement necessary interfaces

```
public class MainActivity  extends BaseActivitiy implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

declare instances

```
  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private Location mLocation;
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

put this in `onCreate()`

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

At last, override necessary methods

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        } startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
```

Don't forget to start GPS in your device before running app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define LocationListener .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude; 
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("Latitude","status");
    }
}
```

And need to give below permission :

**ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**  : It is used when we use network location provider for our Android app.

**ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** : It is providing permission for both providers.

**INTERNET** : permission is must for the use of network provider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of user location:

https://github.com/keithweaver/Android-Samples/tree/master/Location

Answer (score 0):

**you can get current location by using these simple steps**

*give internet permission in manifest file*

*give ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
Button button_location,button_locationinMap,Last_locationUser,shareBtn;
TextView textView_location;
LocationManager locationManager;
ProgressBar SHOW_PROGRESS;
String address;
double latitude;
double longitude;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button_location=findViewById(R.id.button_location);
    textView_location=findViewById(R.id.text_location);
    Last_locationUser=findViewById(R.id.Last_locationUser);
    SHOW_PROGRESS=findViewById(R.id.SHOW_PROGRESS);
    shareBtn=findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
    button_locationinMap=findViewById(R.id.button_locationinMap);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]
                {
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},100);
    }
    shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String uri = "https://www.google.com/maps/?q="+latitude+","+longitude ;
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share in..."));
        }
    });
    button_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getLocation();
            SHOW_PROGRESS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    button_locationinMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GoogleMapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Last_locationUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserLastLocation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void getLocation() {
    try
    {
        locationManager=(LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,50000,0,MainActivity.this);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
        address=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        textView_location.setText(address);
        SHOW_PROGRESS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView_location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
}
```

}